# JDBC data sources

Tags: glassfish, jdbc, java

Привет!
Я использую glassfish, и тут мне в туториале попался дата сурс JNDI-адресом :

> jdbc/__default

какие там данныехранятся, как мне их прочитать??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Там лежит объект. Его нужно достать и привести к нужному типу.

```
Map env = new HashMap();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory");
Context ctx = new InitialContext(env);
// Look up an object
MyType obj = (MyType) ctx.lookup("jdbc/__default");
```

Tutorial - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/